# MVC view model to stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to assign stored procedure result to a view model class in MVC 4?

We are CRUD operations in a single view

```
VMClinics vc = new VMClinics();
var clns= db.USP_GLOBAL_SELECT_CLINICS_WITH_UNIT_ID(id);
return PartialView("_CreateClinics",vclns);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property of Type IEnumerable in VMClinics model.

```
public class VMClinics
{    
 public IEnumerable<ListOfClinics> listOfClinics {get;set;}     
}
```

In your controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 VMClinics vc = new VMClinics() { listOfClinics=db.USP_GLOBAL_SELECT_CLINICS_WITH_UNIT_ID(id).ToList()};
 return PartialView("_CreateClinics",vclns);
}
```